# Keras conv nn predicting only one class?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

So I've been building a convolutional neural network. I'm trying to predict whether a boardgame state (10x10 matrix) will lead to a win (binary 0 or 1) or not.

I have six million examples, which you would think would be enough, but clearly not, as my network is predicting all of one class...

Is there something obvious I'm missing? I tried giving it even 10 examples and it still predicts them all as the same class.

The input matrices are 10x10 of integers.

Input reshaping:

```
x_train = x_train.reshape(len(x_train),10,10,1)
```

Actual model building:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(3, kernel_size=(1, 1), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', input_shape=(10,10,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1, 1)))
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(500, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(75, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1,kernel_initializer='normal',activation='sigmoid'))
optimizerr = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.9, decay=0.01, nesterov=True)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizerr, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=[metrics.binary_accuracy])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,epochs = 100, batch_size = 128, verbose=1)
```

I've tried modifying the learning rate, momentum, decay, the kernel_sizes, layer types, sizes... I checked for dying relu and that didn't seem to be the problem. Removing the dropout/batch normalization layers (or various random layers) didn't do anything either.

The data have roughly 53/47% split across the labels, so it's not that either.

I'm more confused because even when I ask it to predict the train set, it STILL insists on only labeling things one class, even if there are only ~20 samples or fewer.

Comment: The first Conv2D layer seems like an odd choice to me. You apply 32 filters that each view only a single boardgame square at a time. What abstraction is gained here? Also, your input is a single 10x10 grid of integers, but having multiple 10x10 grids of booleans, each layer representing a different piece, might yield better results.

Comment: whoops typo it's not 32 it's 3

Comment: I'd have to pass it 30+ 10x10 grids that are mostly zeroes. That's quite the sparse input, I'll try it though. Unless one grid for each piece, as opposed to each piece for each team, would work, but I doubt it since it couldn't differentiate between whose pieces were whose. Right now I code them to be larger numbers (21-31 as opposed to 1-11, scaled ofc) for the "enemy" team hoping it would get the distinction, but perhaps not.

Comment: Is your loss decreasing on iterations?

Comment: Nope, nor is accuracy increasing. Not out to a hundred and fifty anyways

Comment: Actually ironically enough 32 filters wound up giving me a 15% accuracy increase on the test set, so while I can't really pretend to know what in the hell the model is gaining from that many of them, it must be gaining something! So a note to anyone arriving here, try stupid parameters. They might surprise you!